# Cannot get JS chart to work / draw

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get the path element to draw a line between 2 points on the chart, but unable to. I am using json to grab the data, but it does not put anything on the graph other than the numbers and the dates. What am I missing here?

I also tried to use artificial numbers in my dates / rates array to see if it would draw something, but it hasn't. I'm just not sure how to get it to use the json data to draw a line or a point on the graph.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
 <!-- <script src="charting.js"> </script> -->
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <div class="mypanel"></div>

<script>

function showChart()
{
 d3.json("http://api.fixer.io/2017-01-03", function (jsonData) {

        var width = 800;
        var heigth = 500;

        var margin = 100;

  var chartWidth = width - margin*2;
  var chartHeigth = heigth - margin*2;

  var rates = ['1', '2000'];
  var dates = ['2017-01-03', '2017-02-03'];

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain([d3.min(rates), d3.max(rates)])
   .range([chartHeigth, 0]);

  var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
   .domain(dates)
   .range([0, chartWidth]);

        var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

        var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", heigth);

        var chartGroup = canvas.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + ", " + margin + ")");

        var line = d3.line()
   .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.date) })
   .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.rate) });

        chartGroup.append("path")
   .attr("d", line(jsonData))
   .attr("fill", "none")
   .attr("stroke", "red")
   .attr("stroke-width", "3px")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (100) / 2  + ", 0)");

        chartGroup.append("g")
   .call(yAxis);

        chartGroup.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0, "+chartHeigth+")")
   .call(xAxis);  
 });
}







  //       for (var property in jsonData.rates) {
  //     if (jsonData.rates.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
  //      rates.push(jsonData.rates[property]);
  //            }
  // }

</script>







 <script> showChart(); </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your snippet is showing nothing

Comment: Is it not even showing the graph? The snippet is working on my end.

Comment: No instead it's giving error `{  "message": "Script error.",  "filename": "", "lineno": 0,  "colno": 0}

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to start with. The JSON request is not https, so it's being denied. Once you have that fixed, the CORS headers from api.fixer.io isn't allowing cross-domain use. (I'm not sure that's *all* of what's going on, but it's a start.)